# "Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)" error due to user-defined functions in GEKKO

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, gekko

I try to develop a code for a discrete optimization making use of a catalogue of data via GEKKO. Please see the code below: Whenever I add the part with pandas dataframe (df) in my constraint function (con) I receive the error **"Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)"**.

Would you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
# libraries in use
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd

# building GEKKO model
m = GEKKO() 

integer=[1,2]

x=[m.sos1(integer) for i in range(len(integer))]  
# x = m.Array(m.Var,2)

# example dataframe
data=[[1,5],[2,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['integer', 'catalogue'])

def obj(x,a):
    
    return a*x[0]**2-4*x[1]*x[0]**2+x[1]**2+x[0]**2-x[0]+1

def con(x,a,df):
    
    r = [] 
    for xi in x: 
        print('xi=',xi)
        r.append(df.loc[df['integer'] == xi]['catalogue'].values.item())
    
    return a*r[0]*r[1]**2

# initial guess
ig=[1,2]

i = 0
for xi in x:
    x[i] = ig[i]
    xi.lower = 1
    xi.upper = 5
    i += 1

a=4

m.Equation(con(x,a,df)<=2)

m.Minimize(obj(x,a))
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
m.solve()
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what the code is doing? What is `x`? it's not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code and opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()` reveals the `gk_model0.apm` file that is used by APMonitor to compile the problem into byte-code for solution.

```
Model
Variables
    int_v1 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v2 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    v3 = 0, <= 5, >= 1
    int_v4 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v5 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    v6 = 0, <= 5, >= 1
End Variables
Intermediates
    i0=((0+((1)*(int_v1)))+((2)*(int_v2)))
    i1=((0+((1)*(int_v4)))+((2)*(int_v5)))
End Intermediates
Equations
    ((0+int_v1)+int_v2)=1
    v3=i0
    ((0+int_v4)+int_v5)=1
    v6=i1
    False
    minimize 1
End Equations

End Model
```

There is a problem with the way the last constraint and objective function are defined.

```
    False
    minimize 1
```

A couple additional suggestions are to use integer variables instead of the `m.sos1()` function. The `m.sos1()` function is used when the variables are discrete but not integers. Replace:

```py
integer=[1,2]
x=[m.sos1(integer) for i in range(len(integer))]
```

with the following for a more efficient implementation:

```py
x = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=1,ub=2,integer=True)
```

The `x[i] = ig[i]` changes the type of variable `x` from a Gekko type to an integer. Use `x[i].value = ig[i]` to update the initial guess instead. Based on the statements above, should the upper bound to `x` be `2`, instead of `5`? The lower and upper bounds can be set on variable initialization with `lb=1,ub=2`.

The functions `obj` and `con` are only evaluated once at problem initialization so the catalogue lookup won't update as the values of `x` change. An alternative way to lookup values is to multiply `x` by 5 to get the lookup value. The constraint with `<2` gives an infeasible solution so I changed it to `<1000` to make it feasible. Here is a modified version of your original problem that solves successfully.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
m = GEKKO() 
x = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=1,ub=2,integer=True)
def obj(x,a):    
    return a*x[0]**2-4*x[1]*x[0]**2+x[1]**2+x[0]**2-x[0]+1
def con(x,a):
    r = [] 
    for xi in x: 
        r.append(xi*5)
    return a*r[0]*r[1]**2
# initial guess
ig=[1,2]
for i,xi in enumerate(x):
    xi.value = ig[i]
a=4
m.Equation(con(x,a)<=1000)
m.Minimize(obj(x,a))
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
m.solve()
```

```
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :            3
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            2
   Residuals    :            2
 
 Number of state variables:              3
 Number of total equations: -            1
 Number of slack variables: -            1
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              1
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    8 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  1.22E+00 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   2.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:   1.22E+00 Gap:   4.81E-01
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  2.00E+00 Gap:  4.81E-01
Iter:     3 I: -1 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    1 Obj:  1.22E+00 Gap:  4.81E-01
--Integer Solution:   2.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:   2.00E+00 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    1 Obj:  2.00E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.360000000568107E-002 sec
 Objective      :    2.00000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```